# Combine multiple DataTables into one

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having multiple data table(9 Data table) with columns more than 15 each. Each  datatable having a common field ItemID and equal number of rows. My requirement is to combine these datatables in to one single datatable so that i can bind to a grid.
I tried with dataset Merge function but it takes much time to merge 9 data tables. Is there any other option to do this.

Comment: Are you trying to Union the data or Join based on the `ItemID` field?

Comment: Does the table all have the same columns (name/type)? If not you might use something else than a datatable for your binding.

Comment: @Serge: These datatables having different columns, One column ItemID is common in all datatables.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the database layer, you can create a SQL query that joins each table. Normally operations on large datasets will be significantly faster at the database level rather than the .NET level.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do something like this instead of working with a DataTable.

```
public class RowWrapper
{
    public DataRow TheRow;
    public EType RowType;

    public Enum EType {
        Type1
        , Type2
        , ...
    }

    public RowWrapper(DataTable theRow, EType rowType)
    {
        this.TheRow = theRow;
        this.RowType = rowType;
    }
}

<...>

this.myGrid.DataSource = Table1.AsEnumerable().Select(r => new RowWrapper(r, EType.Type1))
.Union(Table2.AsEnumerable().Select(r => new RowWrapper(r, EType.Type2))
.Union ...
```

Then inside your row binding event handler.

```
var rw = e.Item.DataItem as RowWrapper;
switch (rw.RowType)
{
    case EType.Type1 :
    ...
    case EType.Type2 :
    ...
    ...
}
```